# query a long list using Delphi

Tags: delphi

One of my app needs to query a `String` in a SQLite table. If the `String` is not in table, then add it.

My problem is if the number of items in the returned list is on the smaller side, everything is OK. But, if the list becomes huge, the query processing will takes a long time. Is there a portable memory table or db that can shorten the time?

Comment: If that column is `UNIQUE`, then you can use `INSERT OR IGNORE` statement and let the SQLite do all the work for you without fetching anything to the client side. Here is a [`live example`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/e20b0/1).

Comment: If searching a table for an entry takes a long time, then it sounds like you need an *index* on that column.

Comment: I think if I put the table into memory(any memory database), maybe the query speed will be up.

Comment: Why don't you want to let the engine do the *hard work* for you. It's really enough to add `UNIQUE` constraint to that column. SQLite will create a unique index for you and then you can use just `INSERT OR IGNORE`. That automatically created index will speed up the table lookup rapidly and will not need to fetch anything to your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using index?

Another way could be using unique index then try to insert data everytime and manage the exception in case of duplicate rows..

How many records has your DB (define too many items)?

How long is the string field? Is it a TEXT field?

Please add more information posting an example of your code

Comment: All that you can get by adding unique constraint to the column. It will also guarantee that values there will be unique.